# Wordpress RSS feed - custom post type latest page only

Tags: wordpress, rss

Today I am trying for the life of me to display a RSS feed of a custom post type on a separate WordPress website. I have the custom post type generating a solid RSS feed using the standard Wordpress RSS URL taxonomy (https://www.website.com/page/custom-post-type/?feed=rss2) and am able to display top level category of the custom post type.

However, I can not figure out the correct url taxonomy to only display the most recent post data under that custom post type top level category.

I would assume the correct URL would be something like this - https://www.website.com/page/custom-post-type/?p=latest&feed=rss2 - but this too only shows the top level custom post type so ie (all posts under that post type)

WordPress linking support documentation - https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-feeds/

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.